# Disable enter on form submit but keep enter functioning on inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to disable the enter key for submitting a form and keep the enter key function as default for input fields. Better yet, after typing inside the input field clicking enter would actually tab to the next input. Most importantly however, I am trying to disable enter on submit but keep default function with input fields.

I tried sever different ways to do this. The code below disables enter on submit, but is also disabled with input fields, then the submit button works as a tab. Click it once and it enters the input field, click twice it submits the form. I DON'T WANT THAT.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on( 'keypress', '.product-quantity', function (e) {
        if (e.charCode==13) {
           $(this).parent('#working-space').children('.submit').trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Same goes for this code below. It clicking submit enters the input field, clicking submit again submits the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#working-space').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
         var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
         if (code  == 13) {
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
    }
    });
 });
```

I want to disable the enter key on submit, but not on input fields. Better yet, when on an input field clicking enter tabs to the next input.

Comment: if you could make a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/67/

Comment: Your question has no accepted answer yet. Do you still need additional information?

Answer (score 1):

This [seems to work in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/bU9mu/):

```
$("#form1 input[type=text]").on("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).nextAll("input:first").trigger("focus");
    }
});
```

Comment: that works great. I am just having trouble implementing it into my project

Comment: Change `input[type=text]` to `input[type=text], input[type=number]` (etc). I leave it to you to figure out how to find the next element to focus.